# Hadoop custom Mapper output format to Reducer

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

Pretty new to HDFS:

Correct me if I am wrong but to my knowledge:

`Mapper<Object, Text, Text, Text>`

The last two `Text` are the return types of the Mapper. Say I wanted to return `Text, <Text, IntWriteable>`. How could I achieve this? Also, where in the documentation should I look?

For example, after the mapper receives the Object and Text, it does some logic with the lines of data in the input file, I want it to return something like

`context.write(Text,[Text, IntWriteable])`

Comment: Can you give us a bit more details on the problem you are trying to solve? Without context, it's hard for me to see if what you need is a custom writable type, or if for example just adjusting your mapper output strategy would do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

you have to implement the custom writable in hadoop.I am pointing some sites,might be helpful

https://halalhassan.wordpress.com/2013/12/15/custom-writables-in-hadoop-the-right-way/
http://www.hadoopmaterial.com/2013/10/custom-hadoop-writable-data-type.html

Comment: Would you happen to know how to use globstatus in the Mapper? I am having trouble with that as well. It's been bugging me all day. Sorry to bother you:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29355148/how-to-pass-filesystem-to-mapper-hdfs

Answer (score 1):

You may need to define your own data type. If comparison operation needed, implement [WritableComparable](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/WritableComparable.html) interface, otherwise just implement [Writable](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/Writable.html) interface is ok.

Here is a sample using `WritableComparable` interface:

```
public class MyDataType implements WritableComparable<MyDataType> {
    private Text name;
    private IntWritable age;

    @Override
    public void readFields(DataInput in) throws IOException {
        name.readFields(in);
        age.readFields(in);
    }

    @Override
    public void write(DataOutput out) throws IOException {
        name.write(out);
        age.write(out);
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(MyDataType o) {
        int nameCompare = name.compareTo(o.name);
        if(nameCompare != 0) {
            return nameCompare;
        } else {
            return age.compareTo(o.age);
        }
    }
}
```